# Best Data Structure for mini map

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

I want to develop a mini map for a specific location (e.g. New York), based on any type of Data Structure.
Features of that mini map:

1. Shortest path from source to destination
2. The calculation of distance covered

I need suggestions in deciding the Data Structure.

Comment: Sir Safdar project is seriously dangerous. :D

Comment: @AsadUrRehman yeah :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a graph to implement such project. Additionally, you might find [Dijkstra's algorithim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) useful. It finds the shortest path and keeps track of the cost (distance).

Comment: this should have been a comment

Comment: @Anantha Raju C I cannot comment as I am under 50 rep.

Answer (score -1):

A graph may be useful?  There are many [well-known shortest path algorithms for graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)